# Correct process for reconsideration of flags?

Tags: discussion, flags

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221641/jquery-function-in-function-variable-not-recongnized/15221781#15221781). I flagged one of the 2 "answers" by the OP and the flag was disputed.

The OP has posted an answer showing the Html relating the the Javascript in the Q. I'm still pretty certain it should be merged into the question.

Is it appropriate to just flag again (perhaps with a more detailed reason than "Not an answer") or is that bad form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [that's definitely not an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15222284/99456).

You can edit it in the question yourself, you don't need to flag for that. Since your "not an answer" flag was disputed, a custom flag would be the next logical step. Try to be as clear as possible, and don't forget to mention that you've already edited the "answer" into the question.

If you want to be extra nice, you can post a comment on the "answer", explaining why it should have been part of the question and not posted as an answer. This is probably an instance of forum-itis, in all likelihood the OP doesn't know they could edit their question to add additional information to it.

Comment: Last time I edited an answer into the Q and then flagged, the mod used some tool option which merged the answer into the question again - after some discussion, I was asked not to do that again.

Comment: re: forum-itis, yeah that's how I came across the question... http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/100536/forum-esque-multiple-answers